# Watir: Problems trying to get the value of a field that's contained within an iframe

Tags: iframe, watir

I'm trying to verify the text within a field that's held in an iframe using the shown in the image below.

When I run it I get this syntax error:
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:857:in `method_missing': undefined method` value' for #<Watir::HTMLElement: located: false; {:width=>"100%", :tag_name=>"iframe"} --> {:id=>"P5533_COMPANY"}> (NoMethodError)
from temporary_exp.rb:83:in `'

If I use the code for performing a 'click' e.g. browser.iframe(:width =>"100%").element(id: "P5533_COMPANY").click then it works fine but for some reason it doesn't like 'value'. Any ideas?

[This is the code I'm running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVznp.png)

Answer (score 0):

`#value` is not a method in `Watir::HTMLElement` object, which is what you get an instance of when you use `#element` method. Is the HTML element you are working with a Checkbox? (then use `#checkbox` instead of `#element`)